# Autorun script while plugging in a USB device on a USB-media blocked PC

Tags: usb, scripts, automation, sh, autorun

I have about 50 PCs with Ubuntu versions ranging from 12 to 18. All is USB media blocked. I want to copy a folder from my USB to a standard user account. Every time I have to manually acquire root permissions in terminal, since it's logged in with standard user,then turn off USB block, copy files and turn on USB block.

Is there any way I could do this with script or something? Like... I plug in the USB, wait a few seconds then unplug, the files would be copied, USB block untouched and still logged in as a standard user.

Edit: All the PCs have two accounts. One is root and other is standard. Using root I have blocked the USB media.

Chmod 000 /media/ to block..... And 
Chmod 777 /media/ to unblock.

I don't want the standard users to plug in there usb. I'm a lab assistant of a school. Don't want kids plugging in their USB. But I have to copy files into all systems, into the standard account folder every week. It's a headache.

I know the commands to gain root, unblock, copy file and block. What I'm looking for is... A way to do this all automatically. A friend told me about sh files or scripts and there are auto run features in Ubuntu on events such as USB plug in etc etc.

Any idea if this is achievable?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Note that only Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 is not EOL and thus still on-topic here – you really shouldn’t be running anything <16.04 in any case. How exactly is the USB block achieved, and how do you remove and restore it? Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: If USB is blocked effectively you should be unable to do anything about it with just your USB stick. How about sticking it in, get root to remove the block and then *run a script on the pendrive* which does the whole rest?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you’re not managing these machines remotely, e.g. via `ssh`? I’d set up one machine with a root cronjob deploying the files automatically, this way you just need to store them in the input directory and be done. You just need to install a ssh server on each of the user machines and use `ssh-copy-id` to copy the main machine root user’s public key to them.